# Controllers resource functions not working laravel akaunting opensource

Tags: php, laravel

I have used the laravel akaunting open source software and trying to modify it according to my needs but when I call the function from my route like

```
Route::resource('low-stocks','Reports\LowStock');
```

Or

```
Route::get('low-stocks','Reports\LowStock@index');
```

It does not work and when I call this route it redirects the page into dashboard
But when I write this

```
Route::get('low-stocks','Reports\LowStock@testing');
```

It works

I tried creating permissions in the akaunting prebuild users permissions but it is still doing the same

My whole route.php looks like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'language'], function () {
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

     Route::group(['prefix' => 'reports'], function () {
            Route::resource('income-summary', 'Reports\IncomeSummary');
            Route::resource('expense-summary', 'Reports\ExpenseSummary');
            Route::resource('income-expense-summary', 'Reports\IncomeExpenseSummary');
            Route::resource('tax-summary', 'Reports\TaxSummary');
            Route::resource('profit-loss', 'Reports\ProfitLoss');
            Route::resource('best-seller', 'Reports\BestSeller');
            Route::get('best-seller-monthly', 'Reports\BestSeller@index');
            //It works 
            Route::get('testing', 'Reports\LowStock@testing');
            // It doesnot works
            Route::resource('low-stocks','Reports\LowStock');
        });

  });
});
```

It looks like it is banning to call index , create , edit , delete , store , update function without permission I could not understand it

This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Reports;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Models\Common\Item;
use App\Models\Setting\Group;
use App\Models\Setting\Category;

class LowStock extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function testing()
    {
        $items = Item::with('category')->where('quantity' , '=' ,0)->collect();
        $categories = Category::enabled()->orderBy('name')->type('item')->pluck('name', 'id');

        $genres = Group::enabled()->orderBy('name')->type('item')->pluck('name', 'id');
        return view('reports.low_stocks.index', compact('items','categories','genres'));
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps there is a middleware assigned to those methods .. and what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: please show us the route list. run the command

php artisan route:list 

, also show the LowStock controller

Comment: Edited the answer please check fahim152

Comment: It doesnot works mean I am unable to go to localhost:8000/reports/low-stock
It is automatically redirecting me to dashboard

Comment: Please check the spelling mistake in url: localhost:8000/reports/low-stock and in the route it is plural as low-stocks

Comment: I have added the prefix and url is good

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much hard to maintain a custom module in akaunting. You should read the doc of akunting well.
First you need to create a module for this

```
php artisan module:make Blog

php artisan module:install blog 1   //(1 its your company id)
```

For Better understanding read this two https://akaunting.com/docs/developer-manual/modules
 &  https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v1/advanced-tools/artisan-commands

Comment: Did we have to write all routes , controllers and other components inside modules

Comment: when you write php artisan module:make Blog it will create all for you just override it..You can show there module which is there Offline Payment